# How can i disguise uGet as a browser to circumvent the disabling of an IDM by a website?

Tags: windows, download-manager, user-agent

A website i have used uGet with in the past has swapped to cloudflare and blocked downloads through anything but a standard browser.

My understanding of the matter is pretty limited, but I gather it may have something to do with the useragent?

I have obtained the useragent of my chromium browser and added it to uGet.  I've also added the referrer which if I am correct, is simply the webpage the download links originate from.

Still I've had no success.  Can someone please advise as to what I'm missing in order to return functionality to my download manager?